# How to add an increasing integer ID to items in a Spark DStream

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am developing a Spark Streaming application where I want to have one global numeric ID per item in my data stream. Having an interval/RDD-local ID is trivial:

```
dstream.transform(_.zipWithIndex).map(_.swap)
```

This will result in a DStream like:

```
// key:  0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8  ||  0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4  ||  0
// val:  a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | i  ||  j | k | l | m | n  ||  o
```

(where the double bar `||` indicates the beginning of a new RDD).

What I finally want to have is:

```
// key:  0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8  ||  9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13  ||  14
// val:  a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | i  ||  j |  k |  l |  m |  n  ||   o
```

How can I do that in a safe and performant way?

This seems like a trivial task, but I feel it very hard to preserve state (state = "number of items seen so far") between RDDs. Here are two approaches I tried, updating the number of seen so far (plus the number in the current interval) using updateStateByKey with a bogus key:

```scala
val intervalItemCounts = inputStream.count().map((1, _))
// intervalItemCounts looks like:
// K:  1                                  ||  1                  ||  1
// V:  9                                  ||  5                  ||  1

val updateCountState: (Seq[Long], Option[ItemCount]) => Option[ItemCount] =
  (itemCounts, maybePreviousState) => {
    val previousState = maybePreviousState.getOrElse((0L, 0L))
    val previousItemCount = previousState._2
    Some((previousItemCount, previousItemCount + itemCounts.head))
  }
val totalNumSeenItems: DStream[ItemCount] = intervalItemCounts.
  updateStateByKey(updateCountState).map(_._2)
// totalNumSeenItems looks like:
// V:  (0,9)                              ||  (9,14)             ||  (14,15)

// The first approach uses a cartesian product with the
// 1-element state DStream. (Is this performant?)
val increaseRDDIndex1: (RDD[(Long, Char)], RDD[ItemCount]) =>
  RDD[(Long, Char)] =
  (streamData, totalCount) => {
    val product = streamData.cartesian(totalCount)
    product.map(dataAndOffset => {
      val ((localIndex: Long, data: Char),
           (offset: Long, _)) = dataAndOffset
      (localIndex + offset, data)
    })
  }
val globallyIndexedItems1: DStream[(Long, Char)] = inputStream.
  transformWith(totalNumSeenItems, increaseRDDIndex1)

// The second approach uses a take() output operation on the
// 1-element state DStream beforehand. (Is this valid?? Will
// the closure be serialized and shipped in every interval?)
val increaseRDDIndex2: (RDD[(Long, Char)], RDD[ItemCount]) =>
  RDD[(Long, Char)] = (streamData, totalCount) => {
    val offset = totalCount.take(1).head._1
    streamData.map(keyValue => (keyValue._1 + offset, keyValue._2))
  }
val globallyIndexedItems2: DStream[(Long, Char)] = inputStream.
  transformWith(totalNumSeenItems, increaseRDDIndex2)
```

Both approaches give the correct result (with `local[*]` master), but I am wondering about performance (shuffle etc.), whether it works in a truly distributed environment and whether it shouldn't be *a lot* easier than that...

Comment: The origin of this question is described in my post on the spark-users mailing list: https://www.mail-archive.com/user@spark.apache.org/msg19851.html

Comment: "This seems like a trivial task" -> there's nothing trivial about trying to keep a strictly increasing, gap-less sequence in a safe and performant way in an asynchronous, distributed environment.

Comment: Well, in the case of Spark, I agree that `rdd.zipWithIndex()` is probably complicated, but that exists and is working. For Spark Streaming, after every processing interval, control returns to the driver which can `count()` and which can `transform(_.zipWithIndex)`, and I thought it must be trivial to combine these two steps...